# C++ base class with retain count

Tags: c++

I m writing a library.

WITHOUT using smart pointer. Is it this class safe enough to emulate retain/release behaviour?

Or is there any library already doing things like this?

```
class FooBase {

private:
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_retainCount;

public:
    FooBase()
    {
        m_retainCount = 1;
    };

    virtual ~FooBase()
    {
        assert(m_retainCount == 0); // Prevent from direct delete without release()

        //clean-up if any
    };

    void *release()
    {
        m_retainCount--;
        if (!m_retainCount)
            delete this;

        return this;
    };

    void *retain()
    {
        m_retainCount++;

        return this;
    };

};
```

Comment: Thread-safe, any problems you can think of.

Comment: Why would you write a library that doesn't use a smart pointer? I understand not being able to use C++11 and C++14 features because of a lack of compiler support, but come on, smart pointers are supported just about *everywhere*.

Comment: This doesn't look right. There should be a destructor with automatic cleanup.  `m_retainCount` should be initialized to zero and be careful not to go below zero. `release` doesn't make sense. Give a simple example of what you are trying to do. Use smart pointers if possible.

Comment: "m_retainCount initialized to 1" utilized the concept of objective-c object retainCount. When retainCount goes to 0, the object will be deallocate.

Comment: This doesn't look correct. You'll need to handle copy construction and assignment (and likely move ctor/assignment).

Comment: @CodyGray: The code is already assuming a C++11 compiler. C++03 didn't have `atomic` or any other thread support. I.e. the assumptions are contradicting each other.

Comment: Also, won't calling release ultimately result in a double delete? I'm not sure about this one, but I know that deleting an object twice is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if your thread gets swapped right after the branch in release and before the call to delete.

Another thread could come and request a retain, therefore obtaining a pointer to a soon to be deleted object.

Comment: yeah, thx for your comment rather than promoting smart pointer. just find out the problem you mentioned: If thread1 is already on the "delete this;" line, but thread2 comes to retain it at this point.

Comment: how about using std::mutex to lock it?

Comment: I think you could add `if (!m_retainCount) return nullptr;` in `retain` and handle the `NULL` case from the caller.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part, `std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe. It has the additional benefit of being able to use non-portable tricks internally because it's formally part of the compiler.